# For loop with input file and ftp

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, ftp

I need help writing a for loop to work with ftp. It needs to get its input from a text file of addresses. The script does not need to fully connetct, just show if the host is up or not. what I got so far:

while read p; do
  cat $p
done < /media/C2AF-FE98/ftpsites/list6.txt

I know that there has to be a right way to write this.

Comment: A good approach would be: 1. read each line (done). 2. extract the hostname (and optionally port number) from each line. 3. try to connect to the host/port using `nc -z`. 4. check the exit status and print a message accordingly. Give it a go and ask about anything you're stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

how about the following:

```
for port in 21 990; do    
    while read -r ip; do
        nc -z "$ip" $port>/dev/null && ret="up" || ret="down"
        echo "$ip:$port is $ret"
    done</media/C2AF-FE98/ftpsites/list6.txt
done
```